# How to manage more than one reducer with createContext and useReducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use `createContext` with `useReducer` and have some trouble

I'm dispatching two actions and both actions are storing their payload at the same place in the state, not to their own.

All the help will be appreciated

Here is my store

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, Dispatch } from 'react';

import { InitialStateType } from './types';

import { citiesReducer, CitiesActions } from './citiesReducer';
import { LoadingActions, loadingReducer } from './loadingReducer';

const initialState: InitialStateType = {
  cities: [],
  loading: false,
};

const store = createContext<{
  state: InitialStateType;
  dispatch: Dispatch<CitiesActions | LoadingActions>;
}>({
  state: initialState,
  dispatch: () => {},
});
const { Provider } = store;

const mainReducer = (
  { cities, loading }: InitialStateType,
  action: LoadingActions | CitiesActions,
) => ({
  cities: citiesReducer(cities, action),
  loading: loadingReducer(loading, action),
});

const StateProvider = ({ children }: any): React.ReactElement => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<any>(mainReducer, initialState);

  return <Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export { store, StateProvider };
```

Both reducers

```
import { ActionTypes } from './types';

export type CitiesActions = {
  type: ActionTypes.SET_CITIES_DATA;
  payload: [];
};

export const citiesReducer = (state: [], action: CitiesActions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case action.type:
      return (state = action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

import { ActionTypes } from './types';

export type LoadingActions = {
  type: ActionTypes.LOADING;
  payload: boolean;
};

export const loadingReducer = (state: boolean, action: LoadingActions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case action.type:
      return (state = action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Here I'm dispatching the actions one after another

```
dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.SET_CITIES_DATA, payload: result });
dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.LOADING, payload: false });
```

And as a result, I'm getting in my state

```
cities: false
loading: false
```

instead of

```
cities: [data],
loading: false
```

Comment: Both reducers do not check `action.type` value so all fields are set to the latest action's `payload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the action when handling reducers instead of having a case like `case action.type` in switch statement otherwise regardess of what action you dispatch all reducers will use it and set the payload. In such a case the last actions data will be set for all states

```
export type CitiesActions = {
  type: ActionTypes.SET_CITIES_DATA;
  payload: [];
};

export const citiesReducer = (state: [], action: CitiesActions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.SET_CITIES_DATA: // specify the action here
      return (state = action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

import { ActionTypes } from './types';

export type LoadingActions = {
  type: ActionTypes.LOADING;
  payload: boolean;
};

export const loadingReducer = (state: boolean, action: LoadingActions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.LOADING: // Specify the action here
      return (state = action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```